# Edit the AD user attribute LastKnownParent

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes

I'm facing currently [this](https://support.microsoft.com/hu-hu/help/3133015/sharepoint-server-2013-can-t-import-active-users-through-ad-import-in) issue and the workaround should be to clear the `LastKnownParent` attributes of the users. I've tried many ways to do that, but the result is everytime an error message for example like this:

```
$test = Get-ADUser t.est -Properties *
$test.LastKnownParent = "" # or $null
Set-ADUser -Instance $test
```

> Exception setting "LastKnownParent": "The adapter cannot set the value of property "LastKnownParent"."

[image: Screenshot]

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please include the _entire_ text of the error thrown by PowerShell - the reason for the error is often included, albeit somewhat cryptic.

Comment: It might be that this test user does not have a LastKnownParent attribute because it was never deleted from Active Directory. Try Get-ADUser <user> -Properties * | Get-Member on a real user.

Comment: Do you the running user have permission to do this? Does this work? `Set-Aduser -Identity t.est -Clear LastKnownParent`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I've added a screenshot

Comment: @Mike: Yes, the user has this attribute. Please see the screenshot

Comment: @Matt: You're the WINNER!!!! :)

Comment: Lifetime supply of......

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum per sei. When you mark the answer as solved as you have done that is the indication that you have gotten a satisfactory answer. Title edits are not needed or warranted in this case. I am glad you got this sorted out.

Comment: Thanks for the extra Information. I'm just a rookie on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot answer as to why your method would be failing. All I know is this is the approach I would be taking to remove/clear an attribute in AD user PowerShell

```
Set-Aduser -Identity t.est -Clear LastKnownParent
```

Since `LastKnownParent` does not have its own parameter in Set-Aduser we could `$null` we need to use `-Clear`

This is of course assuming that you have the permissions to make those edits.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I have the necessary permissions.

Comment: I only added that since I didn't know what helped you.